# How to return Value from Controller function to Ajax in View

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, return, return-value

Hi i am basically new to Ajax and having a tough time writing it..

I want to assign src value to Iframe which is fetched from the database
Table is HobbyMasters

```
HobbyName
HobbyUrl
```

I write a function and fetch the url from the table now when i click on Hobbyname which is displayed as link i want that url to be loaded inside the Iframe.

I have written the following ajax function in my View:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('a').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var filename = $(this).text();
          var Hobbyurl = '@Url.Action("FetchUrlByHobbyName")';
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: Hobbyurl,
              data: { data: filename },
              success: function (returndata) {
                  jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(returndata)
                  $('iframe').attr('src', jsonObj.url);
              }
          });
      });
  });
  </script>
```

And the Code for FetchUrlByHobbyName() functioninside the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FetchUrlByHobbyName(string Hobbyurl)
{
    HobbyMasters hobbymaster = new HobbyHomeService().FetchHobbyMasterByHobbyName(Hobbyurl);

    string url=hobbymaster.InformationUrl;
    if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return Json(url);
    return View();
}
```

After after returning it gives me an Exception Error.may be the way i m returning the fetched value is not correct .**Please tell me how shal i return the value to the Ajax** function

Comment: what is on server side? i've done something similar with struts but i don't know what type of action is on your server. Is this struts2?

Comment: @Th0rndike no i am working on MVC3 with Nhibernate

Comment: When doing this on struts i had to get the response writer and send the result over there, then i return null (instead of view in this case). That may or may not get you on the right track.